# OpenNETCF RAPI exception can not be catched

Tags: c#, opennetcf, .net-cf-3.5, rapi

I am using OpenNETCF Desktop Communication Library a RAPI open source library to develop a winform application.

Now everything is OK. But in some computers, the application crashed caused by RAPI lirary and this exception can not be catched.

I debug it and find method **GetDeviceVersion** which calls **CeGetVersionEx** caused a exception.
How can I avoid this exception? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Are you sure you have a `try..catch` block that is catching the right exception type?

Comment: @johnnycardy, I am sure it. May be this exception caused by other thread.